# Double commits in git history after `git format-patch`,`git am`, `git pull`

Tags: git

I develop code on my PC, and I have few computing nodes.

To keep my programs synced I decided to use git. Formerly I used it in a one-way mode to "push-down" changes from PC to computing nodes. However from time to time I encountered small bugs that were specific to computing nodes and fixed it on-site. It was easier to test and develop, than writing on PC and committing a change that might or might not have fixed everything.

I decided to use git utilities to send the changes back up-stream into *main* code base.

I coded fix. Committed it on the computing note, used `git format-patch origin`. Sent patch to my PC and applied it with `git am`. Up to this point everything looked pretty sweet.

However, when I used `git pull` on the computing node it pulled the commit with patch from origin again and `git log` shows two commits with the same comments and authors.

Have I used commands wrong, or my workflow is flawed? Or this is acceptable? (However it doesn't look good to me).

I worked on `master` branches in both cases.

`git pull` computing node:

```
commit 68710f82ddb2b2f191a9c29f088423853032a851  <--- git pull enforced merge
Merge: ce19df4 609b82b
Author: luk32 <luk32@computing.node>
Date:   Fri Dec 13 20:39:28 2013 +0100

    Merge branch 'master' of PC:~/projects/_cmake

commit 609b82bc96f88da956869cec2953e8621cbdcd93  <--- 2nd git pull after git am
Author: luk32 <luk32@computing.node>
Date:   Fri Dec 13 20:35:23 2013 +0100

    Changed to worki with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!

commit ce19df4760519eaf42269461f7bdcf94b65bdc48  <--- on-site fix
Author: luk32 <luk32@computing.node>
Date:   Fri Dec 13 20:35:23 2013 +0100

    Changed to worki with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!

commit ccc5b8a1854e4ca4089cf4c0945baff990288557  <--- after previous git pull
Author: lukas <luk32@PC>
Date:   Mon Jan 16 10:33:11 2012 +0100

    skeleton changed to introduce project stacks
```

`git log` on PC looks fine:

```
commit 609b82bc96f88da956869cec2953e8621cbdcd93
Author: luk32 <luk32@computring.node>
Date:   Fri Dec 13 20:35:23 2013 +0100

    Changed to worki with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!

commit ccc5b8a1854e4ca4089cf4c0945baff990288557
Author: lukasz kucharski <luk32@PC>
Date:   Mon Jan 16 10:33:11 2012 +0100

    skeleton changed to introduce project stacks
```

EDIT:
`computing.node:~/projects/_cmake$ git log --decorate --graph --oneline master`

```
*   68710f8 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'master' of PC:~/projects/_cmake
|\  
| * 609b82b (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Changed to work with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!
| * ccc5b8a skeleton changed to introduce project stacks
* | ce19df4 Changed to work with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!
|/  
* 35d2eaa (origin/pushee) added eigen3 find module
* 39f4937 small bugfixes and slight changes in the reporting of what's going on
```

Comment: Please include the relevant portion of `git log --decorate --graph --oneline master`

Comment: @PeterLundgren Added. I am not a much of git expert. As one can see, so the more details are pointed out the more educational value for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you applied the patch to `origin` and before you ran `git pull`, your history looked like this:

```
  * 609b82b (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Changed to work with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!
  * ccc5b8a skeleton changed to introduce project stacks
* | ce19df4 (HEAD, master) Changed to work with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!
|/
* 35d2eaa (origin/pushee) added eigen3 find module
* 39f4937 small bugfixes and slight changes in the reporting of what's going on
```

Your first commit, `ce19df4`, has `35d2eaa` as its parent. When you applied the patch, you made a second commit, `609b82b`, with `ccc5b8a` as its parent. Because they have different parents, they are *different* commits and have different hashes. The identity of a commit is an agragate of

- A snapshot of the repository (different in the second commit since the repository now has the changes from `ccc5b8a` in it).
- The commit message, author, time (the same since you used `format-patch` and `am`).
- The parent commit (different in the second commit).

So, what does `git pull` do? I don't teach `pull` to new git users, because it's confusing. It depends upon the branch you are on and only works if it's setup as a tracking branch (`master` probably will be, but likely not your other branches unless you set them up yourself). It does two things:

- Fetches remote changes (same as `git fetch`).
- Tries to merge the remote branch with your current branch (same as `git merge`). It only knows what branch to try and merge with if your local branch is set up as a tracking branch.

The `merge` is what's confusing. It tries to do a fast-forward merge ([read more here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)), but can't. So, instead, it creates a merge commit with your local branch as one parent and the remote branch as another parent and you get this:

```
*   68710f8 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'master' of PC:~/projects/_cmake
|\
| * 609b82b (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Changed to work with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!
| * ccc5b8a skeleton changed to introduce project stacks
* | ce19df4 Changed to work with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!
|/
* 35d2eaa (origin/pushee) added eigen3 find module
* 39f4937 small bugfixes and slight changes in the reporting of what's going on
```

While this is a reasonable thing for `git merge` to do, it's not what you want. Who cares that you first made the commit against `35d2eaa`? You really just want `master` to point to the same commit as `origin/master`. You can get there now with:

```
git checkout master
git stash # If you have any uncommitted changes
git reset --hard origin/master
git stash pop
```

And then your history will look like this, just the way you want it.

```
* 609b82b (HEAD, master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Changed to work with MathGL version 2. Broken version 1 compatibility!
* ccc5b8a skeleton changed to introduce project stacks
* 35d2eaa (origin/pushee) added eigen3 find module
* 39f4937 small bugfixes and slight changes in the reporting of what's going on
```

Comment: Thanks for very detailed explanation. I wish I could +2 you, just for the time put =) So I could try to `git pull` before executing the `git format-patch`. I would pull the `ccc5b8a`. And the patch would have it as it's parent. Am I getting it right? But this seems kinda unreliable in the end. Could you please say what do you think proper workflow should be? `patch` `am` `pull` back and `hard-reset`  seem strange/harsh but at least the final result seems ok. Maybe something else than `pull` back is more appropriate a merge kinda gets lost?

Comment: git pull --rebase is probably what you want.

Comment: skorgon is right, `git pull --rebase` would have done what you wanted. Instead of `git pull`, I would recommend `git fetch` and then `git merge --no-ff` or `git rebase` depending upon weather or not you want a merge commit. I find it easier to teach this way. Feel free to use `git pull` again when you fully understand the implications.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is correct and expected when upstreaming through patches. The commit IDs for the commits you did locally the the ones you pulled in from upstream should differ. It looks a little odd, but is the it reflects history correctly as you should see in the graphed view of your history. The changes have been introduced on each branch and won't be deleted from either one. Merge never changes existing history you just add more to your branch.
If you want to avoid having commits "duplicated" you'd have to change to a 'git rebase' based flow instead of merging upstream into your dev branch.

As additional reference, I found this blog article explaining merge vs. rebase which touches the patch problematic as well: http://blog.experimentalworks.net/2009/03/merge-vs-rebase-a-deep-dive-into-the-mysteries-of-revision-control/

Comment: It is just quite strange, because the diff is pretty much the same. It's like applying the same patch two times. Could you please, provide simple example of a `git rebase` workflow and tell its drawbacks? Or tell how to up-stream differently? Perhaps you mean through `push`? Ultimately I would like to avoid double commits, as the look quite strange and kind of pollute history.

Comment: The key is the commit ID, which is different when you apply a patch, compared to using merge to really merge the whole branch. When you rebase you essentially rewrite your branch (changing all the commit IDs of the changes you are rebasing). It takes your local changes and applies them on top of the current upstream branch (or any other fwiw). Rebase would detect that the diff is the same and throw away your local change if it already is in upstream. I think the link I added above explains pretty well how merge vs. rebase works.